# Localization in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, localization

I have a Flash project that I'm working on that will eventually need to be ported to multiple languages.

My approach was going to be to load an XML file that held the localization information, much like the resource files in ASP.NET

I was wondering if there is a better approach to this, or if this is going to be the most straight forward way.

This project is in Action Script 3, and I believe all the international languages will be left to right, however I'm not positive about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [resource modules](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_2.html)?

Comment: Link no longer points to resource modules, did you perhaps mean: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3c.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own, you might also want to consider using [Gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for the job.

Gettext supports features like variables within sentences or pluralization and is rock-solid. Localized resources are compiled, so nobody can tamper with them. Plus, you can use tools like Poedit for translating your files / checking someone else's translation and making sure that all strings are properly translated and still up to date in case you change the underlying source code. I've tried both rolling my own and using Gettext instead and I have to say that Gettext plus [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) were way superior.

There is also a free [Gettext reader](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-for-flash/) for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna be using LTR languages such as Hebrew, you better be using Flash CS4, or you will have to save a reversed version of each string.

Comment: Actually Hebrew is right to left and the languages I'll be using are left to right, so I hopefully won't run into any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm nearly 2 years late, but I just released my AS3 Localization Manager, Babel Flash, you can read about it here:

http://gltovar.com/blog/?p=193

and get the source here

http://code.google.com/p/gltovar/